# Sine integral inequality $\int^{\infty}_{0}\sin(x)f(x)\,dx\leq\int^{\infty}_{0}\sin(x)g(x)\,dx$

Tags: inequality, definite-integrals

Let $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ be two real valued functions such that $f(x)\leq g(x)$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$. Assume that $\int^{\infty}_{0}\sin(x)g(x)\,dx<\infty$. Is it true that $$\int^{\infty}_{0}\sin(x)f(x)\,dx\leq\int^{\infty}_{0}\sin(x)g(x)\,dx$$

Comment: why should that be true? $\sin$ is changing signs.

Comment: for instance if $f(x)=\frac{1}{x}$ for $x>0$ and zero otherwise, while $g(x)=\frac{2}{x}$ for $x>0$ and zero otherwise then on the left you get $\frac{\pi}{2}$ and on the right you get $\pi$. This is one example. I am interested if this is true for any pair of functions satisfying these conditions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not true. Let $f( x ) = 0$ for all $x$ belongs to $\mathbb R, g( x ) = 1$ when $\pi < x < 2\pi$, and $g( x ) = 0$ otherwise.

Comment: I don't think your example contradicts the statement. On the left side one would get $0$ as $f(x)$ is identically zero, on the right side you would get $-\cos(2\pi)-(-\cos(\pi))=-1-(-1)=0$.

Comment: @Adrian $-(-\cos(\pi)) = -(-(-1)) = -1$

Comment: In case $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are non-negative and $0<\int^{\infty}_{0}\sin(x)g(x)\,dx<\infty$ would the statement hold then?

Comment: @Adrian It is the same. Choose an interval in which sin is positive, and modify the f and g above such that they are equal and positive in this interval,and moreover, the integration on it cancel the -2 which make the total integration positive.